Java validator no default constructor found when running in Native mode
I am currently in the process of developing an application where validation takes place. For this I have the following validation class in place:
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IsoCountryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidIsoCountry, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return CountryUtil.isValidIsoAlpha2Code(value);
    }

}

which is used in a Mongo document using the following annotation:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = IsoCountryValidator.class)
public @interface ValidIsoCountry {

    String message() default "A country code must be a valid ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 code";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

When running in normal JVM mode everything works fine. However when I compile into native the following runtime error occurs:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mypackage.validation.IsoCountryValidator.<init>()
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1075)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1238)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2930)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringConstraintValidatorFactory.getInstance(SpringConstraintValidatorFactory.java:56)

I have tried adding the following entries in the reflect-config.json file:
[
  {
    "name": "com.mypackage.validation.IsoCountryValidator",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "queryAllDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "queryAllPublicConstructors" : true,
    "queryAllDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "queryAllPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
    "allPublicClasses" : true
  }
]

and I also tried the following Gradle configuration (graalvmNative task):
buildArgs.add('--initialize-at-run-time=com.mypackage.validation.IsoCountryValidator')

In both cases nothing seemed to resolve the issue.
I am using the latest Spring version with all the native support and I am a bit confused as to what I am doing wrong. Can anyone shed some light?

Solved this on my own. I had the reflect-config.json file in a misspelled directory.
